# SQL server 2005 replication databases in synch

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

we have a 500gb database that performs about 10,000 writes per minute.

This database has a requirements for real time reporting. To service this need we have 10 reporting databases hanging off the main server.

databases in synch in continuously using java any best solution for reduce database transaction